# DATE and TIME from double in PHP

Tags: php, xml, datetime

So, I have this xml file. That has supposedly a date and time in it.but referenced as a double Totally lost. someone please help me convert this into readable format in php.

```
<void property="fstSampleTime">
   <double>1.500464798E12</double>
</void>
```

I don't know how but there is a software known as hoboware that converts this without a problem.

any ideas?

Comment: So, the problem is to get the XML into a double variable? Or to get the double into a readable format? Because [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) returns a double, so maybe that is what you need. After that you can figure out how to format a value returned by microtime. However, it's also possible that the double represents a date in another format, for instance the number of days (including fractions) since 0-0-0000 or sometimes since 31-12-1899. You'll need that information to do the conversion properly.

Comment: What is the date value when converted?

Comment: Pretty sure it could be an offset rather than a timestamp.

Comment: All date and times in the software look like the following

06/05/17 10:00:00 AM

Comment: Out of interest - does the date/time - 10/14/2017 @ 3:26pm (UTC) make sense for the given value?

Comment: I can give the entire xml file if you would like and let it blow your mind lol.

Comment: Fraser, no if you were saying offset. It could possibly be an offset from like implementation date. But it would be around the time given above. June 5th, 2017 . Give or take a month or  so

Comment: Ok. So looking at the hoboware software a bit further. I can delineate that the double that is here should translate to the following

06/05/17 09:00:00 AM

Comment: It does have a timezone after it. Bu tI think it picks that up from a different part of the xml. 

GMT -07:00

Comment: Could you post a pastebin of the xml?